# How do I intentionally trigger an error in fgets()?

Tags: c++, linux, testing, fgets, cstdio

### Summary

When using `fgets()`, I have error checking code that performs some remediation in case `fgets()` returns `null` but isn't yet at end of file. I'd like to exercise this section of code to verify it's working as intended.

Is there a canonical way to trigger `fgets()` to fail? Either through manual means (somehow deleting the file between calls to `fgets()`), some test setup (providing a knowingly "corrupt" file), or something else?

---

### Minimally Reproducible Example

fgets_fail_test.cpp:

```cpp
// Test code to show minimally reproducible example of fgets() error handling
// The desire is to manually trigger a failure in fgets()

#include <errno.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("test_file.txt", "r"); //assume this works, not testing this
    char buf[100]; //assume large enough to hold data
    unsigned int lineno = 1;

    while (fgets(buf, 100, fp)) {
        std::cout << buf;
        lineno++;
    }

    if (feof(fp)) {
        std::cout << "End of file encountered.\n";
    }
    else if (ferror(fp)) { // how do I trigger an fgets error to cause this to return true?
        printf("Encountered read error at line no %u. Error: %d, %s.\n",
               lineno,
               errno,
               strerror(errno));
    }

    fclose(fp); // assume this works, not testing this

    return 0;
}
```

test_file.txt:

```
ABCDEFG
HIJKLMN
OPQRSTU
VWXYZ
The quick brown fox
jumped over the
lazy dog.
Goodbye.
```

---

### Theories

While I could simply replace the code in question with some test scaffolding (write an fgets wrapper that keeps internal state, increment a counter, once it reaches line #N, it returns `null` and manually sets file error and errno) I feel like there *should* be some "builtin" way to do this?

If the only solution is scaffolding, I'll do that. Honestly maybe I'm trying to be too clever here.

Comment: Do you have to use C file handling?  If you are using C++ you can use the C++ file streams and they allow you to set and clear the error bits.

Comment: Since you open in "text mode", what about special characters in the file? By special I mean `(int)charater < 32`

Comment: If you are on a linux system, you can [use one of these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77492/special-file-that-causes-i-o-error).

Comment: @NathanOliver For the purposes of this assignment, I have to use C file handling. It's legacy code that I'm actually working on. I think I'll try to upgrade to C++ file streams when I can in the future, but for this actual work item (and intellectual curiosity) C handling is required. This is a good solution, however, when C++ file handling is used.

Comment: @Ripi2 I tested this just now, and fgets() happily reads special characters without error. Unfortunately this is not a solution :(

Comment: @Artyer I think you might have given me the solution I was looking for. I'm testing some of these methods now, and I'll reply to my original post with the best one (and a relink of the link you provided) once I find the solution.

Comment: You could try doing the operation in a loop, and detaching the device mid-operation.

Comment: @eerorika Can you say more about this? Can a "device" in this case be a single file? Or do I need to detach the entire drive or partition that the device is sitting on? I'm not ruling out any methods here!

Comment: @John I was thinking about the physical hardware. I suspect that unmounting or other virtual operations might be handled too gracefully, though some forceful options might work.

Comment: @eerorika Unfortunately I'm at work and don't have access to the hardware, but I'm always a fan of simplest solution. And honestly, that sounds as simple as possible. When in doubt, smash. Despite not helping *me*, hopefully your suggestion will help *someone* in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many good answers were given in some related and linked questions, which may make my question a duplicate. Although I was focusing on `fgets()` when I did my initial search, so I wasn't able to find these.

Some of the relevant questions are:

- [Special File that causes I/O error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77492/75017)
- [Generate a read error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228509/generate-a-read-error/11362695#11362695)

Because my program reads data from a list of known files with a given filename format, I needed to use a method that allowed me to provide a faulty file to the program (without having to modify code). I decided to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11362695/2027196) answer to do so.

### Method

To generate a faulty file that would trigger a read failure for `fgets()`, I took advantage of `/proc/self/mem`'s "feature" that reading from it will cause an I/O error.

I deleted my old input file, and linked a new one under the old name to `/proc/self/mem`:

```
ln -s /proc/self/mem test_file.txt
```

Running the file then produced the following output:

```
Encountered read error at line no 1. Error: 5, Input/output error.
```

Indicating that we triggered the error. Thanks to @Artyer's comment where they originally linked me to the related questions.